# How to control HTML output of variable $image in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I'm using WooCommerce and on my single product page I have an overview of the product images. I call the images with the product-thumbnails.php template, but the result conflicts with my CSS because the output of $image adds the pixel size in the HTML.

now:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" height="480" width="360">
```

desired:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">
```

**How can i change the output of $image?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5Blank has a pretty good example that should answer some of your questions, take a look [here](https://github.com/toddmotto/html5blank/blob/master/src/functions.php) - spefically line [206](https://github.com/toddmotto/html5blank/blob/master/src/functions.php#L206) and the actions it's hooked into:

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'remove_width_attribute', 10 );

function remove_width_attribute( $html ) {
   $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );
   return $html;
}
```

To specifically target the template you're referring to you could hook specifically into that filter (`woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html`) and modify that function a little like such:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','remove_single_product_image_attrs',10,4);

function remove_single_product_image_attrs( $image_html, $attachment_id, $post, $image_class ){
    return preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $image_html );
}
```

Comment: This works great indeed. I did try to tweak that hook before, but I couldn't get my head around it. Any idea were to find more info about this?

Comment: @user3782713 what are you looking for more information on specifically?

Comment: Everything that is between ( ) of the function. Where are those variables described and how to alter them like you did with `preg_replace`.